# DrawingPanel cannot be resolved to a type, java

Tags: java

I'm working through a textbook for beginners learning java and we are starting to learn about objects. I tried to create a drawing panel using the following code and I got the error DrawingPanel cannot be resolved to a type.

```
package graphics;
import java.awt.*;
   // for graphics

public class Graphics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // create the drawing panel
        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(200, 100);
        // draw a line on the panel using
        // the Graphics paintbrush
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
        g.drawLine(25, 75, 175, 25);    
    }

}
```

I'm a little confused and have looked up other people online having the same problem and not one really giving them any answer as to why this is happening.

Comment: Does awt have a class called `DrawingPanel`? I don't think it does, in which case you'll have to actually find the class code and import it, or add it to your project directory.

Comment: If your text book told you to use getGraphics this way, then throw it away and get a better book, this is not hw custom painting should be done!

Answer (score 2):

DrawingPanel is not part of the Java API.  Your textbook probably has the code for DrawingPanel.java.  So you'll have to create that file and either put it in the same package as Graphics or include an import statement (as @DaaaahWhoosh said).

Answer (score 1):

That's because `DrawingPanel` isn't a standard java `class`. Your textbook is using a third party library, or is a `class` that it has created before.

Answer (score 0):

I check the book and the class file with all the code is included in the book. Your suppost to take the class file from the book and import it in.

Answer (score 0):

I have used DrawingPanel as well, and you must compile the DrawingPanel.java program in the same directory (usually the src folder) that your project .java file is in. Hope this helps! :)